# How to remove this Mavic spoke cover from the rear wheel?

Tags: road-bike, rear-wheel, sprocket

everybody

How do I remove this spline cover from the rear wheel? I'm trying to replace a spoke, but I can't do so because the cover is blocking the way. I've tried using a flathead screwdriver to push against the splines, employing a bottom bracket tool that had splines similar to the ones on the cover, and even prying the cover off, but nothing has worked. Do I need a special tool for this? I've looked up Mavic cog tools but have found nothing. This is on a Mavic Ksyrium SL wheel. This is the first time I've worked on a mavic wheel.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a plain vanilla C ring.  Just spread apart at the gap.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, what are you referring to? I can't spread apart the gap of the part of the hub that holds the spokes.

Comment: Just to the left of center is a gap in the ring.  Jam a large screwdriver into that and spread the gap apart until you can MacGiver it off.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try that. What about the metal cog that's covering it? Would I be able to remove that as well?

Comment: The shiny part?  That looks like part of the casting to me.

Comment: Is the replacement spoke steel? That might be a problem later on. The spoke tensions change when the wheel is in use, and the steel spoke has different elastic modulus, spoke tension will be uneven for part of the wheel's rotation.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, thanks, this resolved the issue.

Comment: @ojs, I believe so. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not worked on this kind of wheel before, but it looks like the ball-end of the spoke is retained in a recess in the hub, and there's a big C clip stopping them from moving sideways (or up as in this photo)

[image]

Option 1: Use a pair of circlip pliers in the Green gap, to spread Yellow circlip apart and ease them over the Red fixed plate.   Do be careful because they may sproing into your face - there's a lot of energy in these.  You might do it with other tools but is even less safe.

Option 2: the red ring may be threaded on, and it may need a simple chain whip to remove.  If so, it may be left or right-hand threaded, and the circlip will just fall off easily exposing the ball joint for your spokes.

---

According to   https://tech.mavic.com/tech-mavic/technical_manual/data/docs/themes/2_12.pdf  page 7, this info is available in "2003 TM page 23"  from [www.tech-mavic.com](http://www.tech-mavic.com) but that requires credentials to log in.

Mavic's public information only spans the last 5 years.

You might find more infomation by checking each wheel at    https://tech.mavic.com/tech-mavic/technical_manual/data/mavic_tech.php?family=1010   and look for a match.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Criggie, I'm still riding these and needed that information.

For anyone else that comes here, the 2003 manual did not have the info. It appeared in a 2004 manual. Here is a link to it - the relevant diagram is on page 9:

[TECHNICAL MANUAL WHEELS+RIMS+SYSTEMS 2004](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0807/5697/files/Mavic_2004.pdf)

The circlip is part number M40467. Pretty much reckon you'd be out of luck if you broke yours!

The removal is easy and can be done with careful use of a small flat blade screwdriver. Pop one end out and work your way around. It is not a strong clip